# MariaDB stops processing queries from all databases

Tags: mysql, deadlock, mariadb

We have `mariadb server` (currently `v10.1`, but same thing happened on `v10.0`), nothing too big, just few GB of data, `9 databases`, each db for different application, so they are not logically connected. All tables are `InnoDB`.

From time to time (usually `0-2 times` per day) `server` stops processing all db related queries (`select`, `update`, `insert`, `alter`, etc) on ALL databases. They just hang/build-up until oldest query reaches about `500s` of lock time, then everything returns to normal. These situations are not registered in `"deadlocks"` section of `"show engine innodb status;"`. And syslog shows only entries like

> "mysqld: 150423 12:07:38 [Warning] Aborted connection 42 to db: 'ejd_im' user: 'ejabberd' host: 'localhost' (Unknown error)".

Configuration:

```
[mysqld]
skip-external-locking

transaction-isolation = READ-COMMITTED

bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

max_connections         = 30
connect_timeout         = 10
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_cache_size       = 64
sort_buffer_size        = 128M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 64M

concurrent_insert       = 2
read_buffer_size        = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size    = 2M
join_buffer_size        = 32M
tmp_table_size          = 64M
max_heap_table_size     = 64M

query_cache_limit       = 4M
query_cache_size        = 64M
query_cache_type        = 1

log_warnings            = 2
slow_query_log          = 1
slow_query_log_file     = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
long_query_time         = 2
log_slow_verbosity      = explain #query_plan

log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index           = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
binlog_format           = 'ROW'

sync_binlog             = 0
expire_logs_days        = 2
max_binlog_size         = 100M

default_storage_engine  = InnoDB
innodb_log_file_size    = 64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
innodb_log_buffer_size  = 8M
innodb_file_per_table   = 1
innodb_open_files       = 1200
innodb_flush_method     = O_DIRECT
innodb_defragment       = 1
innodb_file_format      = Barracuda
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_log_checksum_algorithm = crc32
innodb_use_fallocate    = 1
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode= 2
innodb_ft_sort_pll_degree = 4
```

I've also managed to capture part of output from "show engine innodb status;" regarding oldest waiting transactions:

```
---TRANSACTION 71290030, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 411 sec
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
2 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 153651, OS thread handle 0x7ff144ada700, query id 1459228 localhost nlb query end
REPLACE INTO apiTimings (`userId`, `lastAccess`, `lastIp`, `source`) VALUES ('909', '1429783180', 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx', '1')
Trx #rec lock waits 0 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 0 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
TABLE LOCK table `nlb`.`apiTimings` trx id 71290030 lock mode IX lock hold time 411 wait time before grant 0
RECORD LOCKS space id 484 page no 5 n bits 280 index `PRIMARY` of table `nlb`.`apiTimings` trx table locks 1 total table locks 27  trx id 71290030 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap loc
k hold time 411 wait time before grant 0
---TRANSACTION 71290022, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 412 sec
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
2 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 153644, OS thread handle 0x7ff1449b6700, query id 1459203 localhost nlb query end
REPLACE INTO apiTimings (`userId`, `lastAccess`, `lastIp`, `source`) VALUES ('963', '1429783179', 'xx.xx.xx.xx', '1')
Trx #rec lock waits 0 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 0 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
TABLE LOCK table `nlb`.`apiTimings` trx id 71290022 lock mode IX lock hold time 412 wait time before grant 0
RECORD LOCKS space id 484 page no 5 n bits 280 index `PRIMARY` of table `nlb`.`apiTimings` trx table locks 1 total table locks 27  trx id 71290022 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap lock hold time 412 wait time before grant 0
---TRANSACTION 71290019, ACTIVE 412 sec doing SYNC index
1 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 18987
Trx #rec lock waits 0 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 0 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
TABLE LOCK table "nlb"."FTS_0000000000000321_0000000000000724_INDEX_1" trx id 71290019 lock mode IX lock hold time 412 wait time before grant 0
---TRANSACTION 71290018, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 412 sec committing
2 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 153643, OS thread handle 0x7ff132d93700, query id 1459197 localhost nlb init
COMMIT
Trx #rec lock waits 0 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 0 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
TABLE LOCK table `nlb`.`posts` trx id 71290018 lock mode IX lock hold time 412 wait time before grant 0
TABLE LOCK table `nlb`.`dashboards` trx id 71290018 lock mode IX lock hold time 412 wait time before grant 0
```

Could someone tell me, what the hell is happening or how to diagnose this thing? And why it's affecting all databases?

Edit: apiTiming structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `apiTimings` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastAccess` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `lastIp` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `source` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`),
  KEY `source` (`source`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Another `show engine innodb status;`:

```
---TRANSACTION 75459395, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 362 sec
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
4 lock struct(s), heap size 1184, 4 row lock(s), undo log entries 2
MySQL thread id 1077860, OS thread handle 0x7fcd388d1700, query id 10200793 xen xx.xx.xx.xx yyy query end
REPLACE iplock SET ip = 'xx.xx.xx.xx', count = '1', lut = '1430055393'
Trx #rec lock waits 0 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 0 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
TABLE LOCK table `main`.`iplock` trx id 75459395 lock mode IX lock hold time 362 wait time before grant 0
RECORD LOCKS space id 677 page no 9 n bits 744 index `ip` of table `main`.`iplock` trx table locks 1 total table locks 4  trx id 75459395 lock_mode X lock hold time 362 wait time before grant 0
RECORD LOCKS space id 677 page no 15 n bits 264 index `PRIMARY` of table `main`.`iplock` trx table locks 1 total table locks 4  trx id 75459395 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap lock hold time 362 wait time before grant 0
RECORD LOCKS space id 677 page no 9 n bits 744 index `ip` of table `main`.`iplock` trx table locks 1 total table locks 4  trx id 75459395 lock_mode X locks gap before rec lock hold time 362 wait time before grant 0
---TRANSACTION 75459393, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 362 sec
1 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 45, OS thread handle 0x7fcade563700, query id 10200790 localhost 127.0.0.1 ejabberd init
commit
Trx #rec lock waits 0 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 0 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
TABLE LOCK table `ejd_im`.`spool` trx id 75459393 lock mode IX lock hold time 362 wait time before grant 0
---TRANSACTION 75459390, ACTIVE 362 sec doing SYNC index
1 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 18453
Trx #rec lock waits 0 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 0 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
TABLE LOCK table "nlb"."FTS_0000000000000321_0000000000000724_INDEX_1" trx id 75459390 lock mode IX lock hold time 362 wait time before grant 0
---TRANSACTION 75459389, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 362 sec committing
2 lock struct(s), heap size 360, 0 row lock(s), undo log entries 3
MySQL thread id 1077859, OS thread handle 0x7fcd355d0700, query id 10200783 localhost nlb init
COMMIT
Trx #rec lock waits 0 #table lock waits 0
Trx total rec lock wait time 0 SEC
Trx total table lock wait time 0 SEC
TABLE LOCK table `nlb`.`posts` trx id 75459389 lock mode IX lock hold time 362 wait time before grant 0
TABLE LOCK table `nlb`.`dashboards` trx id 75459389 lock mode IX lock hold time 362 wait time before grant 0
```

Comment: Plz provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE apiTimings;`

Comment: Are you sure there is no `ALTER` or `mysqldump` or other type of backup going on?  Is this in a VM?  On a Hosted server?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE` added to the end of the post. I'm sure there is no `ALTER` or any kind of backup running that time. Besides event if there were, they lock individual tables, not all tables in all databases. During these events CPU and disks are more or less idling. Additionally, I've checked, while `mysqldump` is active, server is able to process queries (it is just little slower).  This is not VM. DB is running on dedicated server: Core i7/16G RAM/2xST33000651AS (RAID1).

Comment: If the `500` is somewhat consistent, run `SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Value BETWEEN 400 AND 600;`

Comment: I can't think why this would help, but try replacing `REPLACE` with an equivalent `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`.

Comment: I've did something else, `show variables like '%timeout%'`, this showed up `deadlock_timeout_long`. But even if I lower it, and it works, this does not solve the problem. I can check changing `REPLACE` to `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE`, but I don't believe its relevant. I may be wrong, but it seems to me that inserts into `apiTimings` table are "victims" of oldest locked transaction which is stuck on `commit` phase. And for some weird reason all queries are waiting for this commit to complete, even if they are not for tables in this db.

Comment: "Description: Long timeout in microseconds for the two-step deadlock detection. Only used by the Aria storage engine." -- MariaDB manual on `deadlock_timeout_long`.  The default is 50s, not 500s.  And if you are not using Aria, it should have no effect.

Comment: `posts` and `dashboards` are also mentioned, plus something to do with a `FULLTEXT` index.  Any clues there?  Also, take another `show engine innodb status;`

Comment: Well, posts has `FULLTEXT` index on it, maybe this two operations clash? But why this index is being modified as separate transaction? Anyway, I've disabled search and removed this index. Will see what happens. But this thing look like a bug to me. Oh, and I've added another output from `show engine innodb status;` to the question.

Comment: I agree that it _may_ be a bug, but I would hope to narrow it down before writing a bug report.  Are `posts` and `dashboards` InnoDB?

Comment: Yeah, everything is InnoDB (it was setup this way for galera, but (for now) galera hasn't been used), only `mysql` db has Aria/MyISAM tables.